# RFP30N06LE question on current

Tags: mosfet, relay

I have a [RFP30N06LE](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf).  I currently have it controlling a 5 V relay via a pin on my ESP-01, however I'm only ever driving/sinking 24 V.  The MOSFET has a range up to 30 V, so is the relay redundant, i.e: can I just use the MOSFET and eliminate the mechanical relay altogether?  Secondary question, if I'm driving voltage up to near maximum, should I ensure there's a heatsink on the device?

The solenoid pulls 0.41 amps maximum inrush, and when holding around 0.14 current.  The relay will be switching via a 24 V separate power supply.

Comment: What does your relay drive? What's the load current? Without these information your questions can't be answered.

Comment: Thanks @RohatKılıç The relay is driving an irrigation solenoid.  A minimum of 19.6v to start opening the valve and up to 24v for fully open at approximately 0.41amps inrush with around 0.14 holding current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

24V at 410 mA maximum inrush current should be absolutely fine for a MOSFET to directly switch.

At the low current here, you won't even need to worry too much about heatsinking or gate drivers, you could do it straight from a microcontroller or whatever.

A flyback diode should be used across the inductive load (reverse biased) to prevent back-EMF voltage potentially damaging the transistor.

However, this assumes it is 24V DC - irrigation solenoid valves are often run off 24V AC as this prevents accelerated corrosion due to electrolysis if water gets into the solenoid or wiring.

A MOSFET can only switch DC. (Other options, like a Triac, are possible for switching AC.)

Comment: Oh that's a very good point.  I missed the important part of the datasheet that says the solenoid I have is 24V AC!  I am using a flyback diode, so I am good there.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I didn't know about the corrosion either.  Thank you! @luke